# How to view elements horizontaly in python-django

Tags: python, html, css, django

How to align the elements in an horizontal manner using list view in python-django.

By using List view the default action of vertical alignment takes place

the below code gets the data from the DB and displays in a vertical aligned form

python:-

```
class HomePageView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Events_List'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.order_by('id')
```

HTML:-

```
<div id="Events">
    <h2>Events</h2>
    {% if Events_List %}
        {% for Events in Events_List %}
            <div id="Events-list">
               <p>{{Events.Event_title}}</p>
            </div>
            <p></p>
        {% endfor %}
     {% else %}
         <p>No polls are available.</p>
     {% endif %}
 </div>
```

Screenshot:-

[image: Screenshot]

I need to align these divs horizontally

Comment: use `#Events{display:flex}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be like this

```css
.boxes > div{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div>box1</div>
  <div>box2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a demo or show me your plain html/css code